# How to set up firebase custom claims from command line?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

People have looked at similar issues before, but the latest I could find is 2018.

How do you set custom claims in firebase with the terminal?

I want to execute a script that sets users with specified emails to admins.

The script is:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()

const adminEmails = [
    "test1@test.com",
    "test2@test.com",
    "test3@test.com"
]

for (let adminEmail of adminEmails) {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(adminEmail)
    .then(function(userRecord) {
      // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
      console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
      admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, {admin: true}).then(() => {
          // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
          // next time a new one is issued.
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
     console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
    });
}
```

When I run this with node, I get invalid credential - how do I authenticate from the command line and is it possible to run a script that creates custom claims like this?

Comment: The Firebase CLI is not going to help you run scripts or deal with custom claims.  I'm confused why you're mentioning Cloud Functions here, since your code isn't declaring a function.  Please edit the question to be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish and what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question Doug - I'm enjoying your tutorial videos! Will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that you need to pass an object with service account credentials to `initializeApp()` to configure the Admin SDK, or set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk).